# Customize report layout odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I customized `external_layout_header` to repeat `vendor`&`shipping address` in `Purchase Order`. Its success fully reflected. But problem is, the content in `div class='page'` overlap the the header. I gave `margin-top:xx` to `class='page'` but its not affected. How can i achieve this?

***external_layout_inherit.xml**

```xml
<template id="purchase_extrenal_layout" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
     <xpath expr="//div[@class='row zero_min_height']" position="before">
     <div class="row zero_min_height">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
<div class="row">

      <div class="" style="float:left; text-align:left; margin-left:50px;">
        <strong>Customer address:</strong>
          <div t-field="o.partner_id"
              t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone", "fax"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
              <p t-if="o.partner_id.vat">VAT: <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></p>
      </div>
      <div style="float:right; text-align:right; margin-right:50px;">
        <strong>Shipping address:</strong>
        <div t-if="o.dest_address_id">
            <div t-field="o.dest_address_id"
                t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone", "fax"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
        </div>

        <div t-if="not o.dest_address_id and o.picking_type_id and o.picking_type_id.default_location_dest_id">
            <span t-field="o.picking_type_id.default_location_dest_id.partner_id.name"/>
            <div t-field="o.picking_type_id.default_location_dest_id.partner_id"
                t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "phone", "fax"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Sample report.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header and footer "margins" are set in the documents paper format. So you have to either change the default paper format, which should be used for most of the reports in Odoo, or you create a new one and link it to purchase order report.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your report file.

```
<record id="paperformat_rfq" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">A4 Barcode Paper</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True" />
    <field name="format">A4</field>
    <field name="page_height">0</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
    <field name="margin_top">8</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">0</field>
    <field name="margin_left">3</field>
    <field name="margin_right">0</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
    <field name="header_spacing">5</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
</record>

<record id="action_request_quotation" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="your_module_name.paperformat_rfq"/>
</record>
```

**Adjust margin_top and header_spacing according to your need.**